# Simulate image capturing on Android

Tags: android, camera

The problem: There is an Android application which uses camera for capturing images(both front and rear orientation) and scanning QR/PDF417 codes.
There is need to test automation of scanning process.

I see this kind of solution: take image from SD card, and put it on active camera preview screen, and than scan/capture it with application.

Appium is used as automation tool, Android real device & Emulators.

How this could be done?